# How to send authorization header to a http request in angular js (version 1.4.8)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[snapshot on server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdUK9.png)

The above screenshot is while I debug the web service which is hit during my javascript call. I want to set the authorization header of the http request which is returning null. Can you please suggest me for this

Answer (score 2):

```
 var config = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://somesite.com/',
      headers: {
            // key value pair of headers
            'Authorization': 'Your auth key'
      },
      data: body of request
  };
 $http(config)
         .success(function(){})
         .error(function(){})
```

Comment: m getting error when seeing in the console Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://82.223.29.24/SIUKService/Api/Login/loginUser. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your `http` request:

```
headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic key'}
```

Examples

GET request:

```
$http.get('url', { //same for post also
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic key'}
});
```

Post Request:

```
$http.post("url", requestData, {
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic yourkey'}
}).success(function(responseData) {
    //do stuff with response
});
```

Comment: @user3012606 added post request example